# Building a basic custom Facebook / Instagram feed for websites (in late 2019)

Tags: facebook, instagram

We build website templates for multiple users, which are all hosted at a different URL. Some request a custom Facebook / Instagram feed of their profile. This used to be fixed really easy with some jQuery plugin or something else, but ever since Facebook's new data policies it requires us to go through App review.

My problem is, I don't have a 'app' with a login procedure, so I can't really implement Facebook login with OAuth nor can I go through the steps needed to get a permanent access token with the permissions I need. How do I access the Facebook and Instagram API for just a regular website? Does this still happen at all?

Comment: _“My problem is, I don't have a 'app' with a login procedure”_ - so, go and fix that problem then :-) Create an app, implement login, make your users who want such a feed login & create an access token …

Comment: Would it be possible to build an app that handles the authentication part for us, but then use the data on a different URL instead of IN the app? @04FS

Comment: As long as you’re just making server-side API calls, that would be no problem. (Anything client-side, that requires the JS SDK, will probably not work, because that usually refuses to properly initialize on anything but the specified app domain.)

Comment: Problem is, we call everything client-side.. The feeds will be build on the websites itself, each on a different URL, as we access a different page/profile per site @04FS

Comment: Nah, client-side is a no-go here in a scenario like this to begin with - you would have to expose your client’s access tokens in publicly visible code. Plus, you’d probably run into the API [rate limits](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/overview/rate-limiting) quickly. Client-side is only an option, if you make the website _visitor_ log in to your app on the site, and then use _their_ access token for API requests.

Answer (score 0):

### Update (June 2021)

jQuery plugin [jQuery.instagramFeed](https://github.com/jsanahuja/jquery.instagramFeed) has been archived due to Instagram updates rendering it inoperative.

I searched far and wide and came to the conclusion that (currently) there isn't any legitimate way to display an Instagram feed on a website without using the API. At this point in time all the workarounds that I found are leveraging proxy servers to circumvent the restrictions that Instagram have in place. Any of these "solutions" are ultimately hacks and (in my opinion) not suitable for production due to lack of stability.

---

### Original Solution (April 2021)

Here is a solution for building an Instagram feed that doesn't involve use of the Instagram API. It's a jQuery plugin called [jQuery.instagramFeed](https://github.com/jsanahuja/jquery.instagramFeed). I will update my answer if I find a viable alternative.

It doesn't require any authentication, simply the Instagram username.

The only potential drawback is that this plugin will only work with Instagram accounts which are set to public. Then again, for many use cases, this likely isn't a problem - because if someone is wanting to display their Instagram feed on their website, they are probably going to want their account to be public anyway.

Here's a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/indieweb/o4mzfk16/). I would have preferred to just add a code snippet here but StackOverflow hasn't made it very feasible yet.

```
<div id="instagram-feed"></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.sowecms.com/demos/jquery.instagramFeed/jquery.instagramFeed.min.js">

<script>
    (function($){
        $(window).on('load', function(){
            $.instagramFeed({
                'username': 'github',
                'container': "#instagram-feed",
                'display_profile': true,
                'display_biography': true,
                'display_gallery': true,
                'display_captions': true,
                'max_tries': 8,
                'callback': null,
                'styling': true,
                'items': 8,
                'items_per_row': 4,
                'margin': 1,
                'lazy_load': true,
                'on_error': console.error
            });
        });
    })(jQuery);
</script>
```

Comment: jquery.instagramFeed is not working anymore and the repo has been archived. Take a look at https://github.com/restyler/inwidget-proxified as a server-side alternative.

Comment: Wow! Ironic timing! Thanks for letting me know. I'll update my answer for now to reflect this and will update again if/when I find an alternative solution.